# Is it possible to Spy (ChanSpy) on a channel running on a difference Asterisk Server

Tags: asterisk, amazon-ami, asteriskami

We have multiple asterisk server running completely independent with agents logged on to these servers.
On the other hand a supervisor logged on to a sip server A wishes to Spy on a target agent logged on Server B who may or may not be talking to a customer.

While I have ChanSpy working on Box C where both supervisor and agent are logged in, the question is, Is it possible to Listen-in from Server A to Server B? given that i know the target channel on server B.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is posible.

You need setup interconnection between servers and call to server B to spy extension(need allow server A to call that extension on B).

For how to setup interconnection between asterisk server - check google or any book like O'Relly "The future of telephony".

Comment: Thanks Arthops. Splendid idea and reference.